# Unable to open the Web site 'bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/publish'. The Web site 'bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/publish' does not exist

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on a .net core 3.1 MVC web application in Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.4.5.

A local folder profile is set up for `bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/publish` and I can publish the entire project to this folder fine. But when I try to publish individual files, I get the error:

> Unable to open the Web site 'bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/publish'.  The
> Web site 'bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/publish' does not exist.

So I'm having to publish entire project even for a one line change in CSS.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

**EDIT**
To reproduce simply create a new asp.net core MVC project in Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.4.5., Publish, select new folder profile (keep default values) and Publish. It will publish to `<your project path>/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/publish`. Now open any View and use the publish shortcut Alt + ; + p (single file publish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your error.And you can change your publish setting with a full path,and then it will work.

This may be your target location.

[image]

You can create a folder like this:
[image]